# How to implement single-line ellipsis with CSS

Tags: css

I want to be able to add three dots and maintain a text in a single line in a responsive design.

So for example:

I have a link with a link inside a container element (e.g. `<span>`).  If the text is long, it will shown in two lines one a small screen:

```
This is a very long text
and it wraps because it's very long
```

I want that text to be shown like this:

```
This is a very long text...
```

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` works if you have set a width to the container, but in responsive design and on my web app it's not specified obviously.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="itm-title">
  <a href="/friendly-url-sample/">This is a very long sentence and I don't want it to wrap, I want three dots</a>
</div>
```

Is there a solution in **CSS or jQuery** that can solve this? thanks.

Comment: Use min-width: 200px or media query to make fit the space you need.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You actually don't need `width` to be "set" here. All the elements in the responsive design have their width. You can just do it around with the following rules:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

**Comment:** This doesn't work with anchor:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept. Learn more about incognito browsing.</a>
```

**It works! `:)`**

- No `width` set.
- Using `<a>` tag.

**Updated with OP's Code**

```css
.itm-title {
  width: 150px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="itm-title">
  <a href="/friendly-url-sample/">This is a very long sentence and I don't want it to wrap, I want three dots</a>
</div>
```

**Result: Works!**

Comment: I have a link <a>, I put the code on the link that wraps in a responsive design and I see a long line of text, all the text, without the ellipsis (tested in Chrome)

Comment: @IdanShechter Add the code man! Only then we can help right? Where did you even mention there was an `<a>`? Do you expect us to read the mind?

Comment: @krillgar Anchor supports too. Only when the code is known, we can help in depth...

Comment: OK, I thought it's a general question regarding any inline element. I'll add the code in a second.

Comment: @IdanShechter Check the updated answer. **It works on anchor tags!**

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize you were still around to comment. As you said, code from the OP would have been infinitely helpful.

Comment: @krillgar Done! Man, I just added the answer!

Comment: @IdanShechter Added solution for your updated question.

Comment: Not in my site. I assume that Zurb Foundation does something. I accept the answer and I find a way around that. If it works I'll make it works on my site.

Comment: @IdanShechter Lemme know if you have further issues. I will be glad to help you... `:)`

Comment: Sure I will, three minutes left :)

Comment: I can't believe it, it worked, I mean accepting the answer :))

Comment: @IdanShechter Thank you so much. Keep me updated with Foundation stuff. `:)`

Comment: @IdanShechter ha ha ha! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar the display:table on the upper-upper parent prevented it, now it works. Thanks so much Praveen (BTW, you are a great guy)

Comment: I have been looking for the trick long time.