# How can I make this text overflow effect using css?

Tags: css, material-ui

How can I make this text overflow effect?

This information is being displayed within a MUI Card of a fixed width.
This is what my code looks like:

```
cardContent: {
    fontWeight: 700,
    color: "#0E0E0E",
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
},
cardComment: {
    fontWeight: 400,
    color: "#0672CB",
    fontSize: "16px",
    lineHeight: "24px",
    textDecoration: "underline",
    width: "100px",
    "&:hover": {
        color: "#0672CB",
        textDecoration: "underline",
    },
},

...
<Typography className={classes.cardContent}>
    Comment: <a className={classes.cardComment}>{group.SizingComments}</a>
</Typography>
```

[image]

Comment: You can refer this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294054/how-to-implement-single-line-ellipsis-with-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement single-line ellipsis with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294054/how-to-implement-single-line-ellipsis-with-css)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.cardContent {
  display: flex;
}

.cardComment {
  width: 180px;
  /*You have to provide width here*/
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardContent">
  Comment:<a class="cardComment" href="javascript:void(0);">Begining of the comment some example text</a>
</div>
```

- All you need is just add the below CSS to `.cardComment` class and provide `width` to see `text-overflow:ellipsis` in effect.

```css
.cardComment {
      width: 180px;
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This will not work for anchor elements

Comment: Agree I have changed my answer added width which is needed for the solution